# Ajustar colunas de acordo com tamanho disponível da JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho uma `JTable` onde o usuário pode ocultar e depois exibir novamente uma ou mais colunas.
Encontrei um código [neste link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) que ajusta a coluna de acordo com o tamanho do "valor do campo". Chamo este método assim que populo a `JTable`.

```
public void defaultSize(JTable table) {
     final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        int width = 250;
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);
            columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
        }

    }
```

No evento do `JRadioButton`, onde o usuário oculta ou mostra novamente a coluna, tenho este código:

```
private void jRadioCodigoItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                              
        int width = 80;
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(0);
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);
            defaultSize();
        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(width);
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(width);
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(width);
            jTableResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(width);
             defaultSize();
        }

    }
```

O que eu queria agora era que, quando ocultada uma coluna, o restante das colunas fosse ajustada de acordo com o tamanho restante da `JTable`, de forma que não ocorra conforme a imagem abaixo mostra. E também que, ao invés de passar o valor para o tamanho da coluna, ao exibi-la novamente no evento do `jRadioButton`, que fosse ajustado de acordo com o tamanho do valor do campo, igual ocorre quando chamo o método `defaultSize()` (só consigo isto ao carregar a tabela na primeira vez).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo reduzido do código:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 *
 * @author LockDown
 */
public final class NovoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NovoJFrame
     */
    public NovoJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        loadtable();
    }

    public void loadtable() {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setNumRows(0);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Rodrigo", "32", "Masculino"});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Elza", "32", "Feminino"});
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Nome", "Idade", "Sexo"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jRadioButton1.setText("Nome");
        jRadioButton1.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton2.setText("Idade");
        jRadioButton2.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton2ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton3.setText("Sexo");
        jRadioButton3.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton3ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(292, 292, 292)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                        .addGap(0, 375, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton3))
                .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                               
        int width = 100;
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
            jTable1.revalidate();

        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(width);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
            jTable1.revalidate();

        }
    }                                              

    private void jRadioButton2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                               
        int width = 100;
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(0);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
            jTable1.revalidate();

        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(width);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
            jTable1.revalidate();

        }
    }                                              

    private void jRadioButton3ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                               
        int width = 100;
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(0);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
            jTable1.revalidate();

        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setWidth(width);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(width);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
            jTable1.revalidate();

        }
    }                                              
    public void defaultSize(JTable table) {
       final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            int width = 250;
            for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);
                columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
            }

        }
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NovoJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Tente executar  `jTableResultado.revalidade();` logo depois de `defaultSize();` no método `jRadioCodigoItemStateChanged`, para ver se a tabela atualiza.

Comment: @diegofm acrescentei um "exemplo" de código, para melhor entendimento do contexto. o `Revalidate()` não teve efeito.

Comment: Você desligou o autoresize da jtable ne?x Não é possivel simular o problema, não tem o metodo initicomponents no código.

Comment: Sim, desliguei. Adicionei novamente o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de analisar seu código, percebi que o `JTable` usa como valor máximo de largura de cada coluna o valor de [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html)(você deve estar criando pela *GUI-builder*, por isso este comportamento), que representa o valor máximo de um inteiro. Ao zerar todas as informações de largura da coluna, você acaba perdendo essa característica, pois o valor máximo será aquele que você configurar novamente, e no código você está configurando como 100.

Para tentar contornar isso, criei um método a parte onde você redimensionará as colunas, de acordo com a seleção dos `JRadioButton`:

```
private void resizeWidthColumn(int indexColumn, int widthColumn) {
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setMinWidth(widthColumn);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setMaxWidth(widthColumn == 0 ? widthColumn : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setWidth(widthColumn);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setPreferredWidth(widthColumn);
}
```

e dentro dos [`ItemListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) dos `JRadioButtons`, chamei este método com valor que você estava passando na condição:

```
private void jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    int widthColumn = 100;
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        resizeWidthColumn(0, 0);
        defaultSize(jTable1);

    } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
        resizeWidthColumn(0, widthColumn);
        defaultSize(jTable1);
    }
}

private void jRadioButton2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    int widthColumn = 100;
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        resizeWidthColumn(1, 0);;
        defaultSize(jTable1);

    } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
        resizeWidthColumn(1, widthColumn);
        defaultSize(jTable1);

    }
}

private void jRadioButton3ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    int widthColumn = 100;
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        resizeWidthColumn(2, 0);
        defaultSize(jTable1);

    } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
        resizeWidthColumn(2, widthColumn);
        defaultSize(jTable1);
    }
}
```

Perceba que em `setMaxWidth()`, eu fiz uma pequena condição, e é essa condição que foi determinante para retomar o valor máximo anterior da coluna, que era `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE`, caso `JRadioButton` esteja sendo desmarcado, e zero se ele estiver sendo marcado.

Com esta solução, não é necessário(e segundo os testes que fiz, não seria recomendado) alterar o modo de redimensionamento(autoReziseMode) padrão da `JTable`, pois pode causar um redimensionamento não desejado.

Com isso, o código final(e testável feito usando a GUI-builder do netbeans) ficou desta forma:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public final class NovoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NovoJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        loadtable();
    }

    public void loadtable() {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setNumRows(0);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Rodrigo", "32", "Masculino"});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Elza", "32", "Feminino"});
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Nome", "Idade", "Sexo"
                }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jRadioButton1.setText("Nome");
        jRadioButton1.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton2.setText("Idade");
        jRadioButton2.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton2ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton3.setText("Sexo");
        jRadioButton3.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton3ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(292, 292, 292)
                                        .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                        .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                                        .addGap(0, 375, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton3))
                        .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    private void jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        int widthColumn = 100;
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            resizeWidthColumn(0, 0);
            defaultSize(jTable1);

        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            resizeWidthColumn(0, widthColumn);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
        }
    }

    private void jRadioButton2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        int widthColumn = 100;
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            resizeWidthColumn(1, 0);;
            defaultSize(jTable1);

        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            resizeWidthColumn(1, widthColumn);
            defaultSize(jTable1);

        }
    }

    private void jRadioButton3ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        int widthColumn = 100;
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            resizeWidthColumn(2, 0);
            defaultSize(jTable1);

        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            resizeWidthColumn(2, widthColumn);
            defaultSize(jTable1);
        }
    }

    private void resizeWidthColumn(int indexColumn, int widthColumn) {
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setMinWidth(widthColumn);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setMaxWidth(widthColumn == 0 ? widthColumn : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setWidth(widthColumn);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexColumn).setPreferredWidth(widthColumn);
    }

    public void defaultSize(JTable table) {

        final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            int width = 250;
            for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);
            }
            columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NovoJFrame().setVisible(true);
                System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;

}
```

Demonstração de funcionamento:

[image: gif animado com o funcionamento do redimensionamento]

Dá pra unificar esses 3 métodos dos `JRadioButton`, que fazem a mesma coisa, passando apenas o índice da coluna, mas não fazia parte da dúvida, preferi não alterar o código mais do que fosse necessário.

Comment: Vou tentar adequar meus códigos aqui, obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Então, deu certo, porém, tenho `strings` bem extensas na `jTable`, desta forma o valor aparece incompleto, devido a ter retirado o  `jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);` do código. Estou tentando resolver, mas até agora  nada.

Comment: @Rodrigo não querendo complicar seu projeto, mas talvez seja uma melhor alternativa criar um cellrenderer e aplicar um JTextArea pra essas células que tem um texto muito grande, pois dai você pode quebrar linhas e exibi-las sem ter que ficar dimensionando a tabela. Imagina se as strings, com tamanho combinado, ficar desproporcional ao monitor?

Comment: Desproporcional ao monitor não vai, mas vai ficar maior que o espaço ao qual está sendo dividido no momento.

Comment: Na verdade são 17 colunas, esse está sendo o problema, para ser mais claro, então o espaço para cada uma após redimensionar a jTable fica pequeno para cada coluna.