# Exibir varias colunas

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou desenvolvendo um programa básico em Aplicação Java (Desktop) que realiza um simples cadastro e exibe em outra tela através de um JTable os dados gravados no mesmo.

O meu problema é que são 24 colunas para serem exibidos nessa tabela, sendo assim não consigo visualizar todos os dados conforme o necessário.

Segue abaixo a imagens demonstrando como a tabela fica.

Obs: O tamanho individual das colunas se alteram (Aumenta uma, diminui as outras automaticamente), porém o tamanho total da mesma fica inalterado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código dessa tela:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package view;

import controller.CadInternoJpaController;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import model.CadInterno;

/**
 *
 * @author Casa
 */
public class JFAltExc extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JFAltExc
     */
    public JFAltExc() {

        initComponents();

        readJTable();

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void readJTable(){

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jtCadInterno.getModel();

        tableModel.setNumRows(0);



        EntityManagerFactory objFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CERVPU");
        EntityManager manager = objFactory.createEntityManager();
        CadInternoJpaController jpa = new CadInternoJpaController(objFactory);
        try{
            for (Iterator<CadInterno> it = jpa.findCadInternoEntities().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                CadInterno c = it.next();
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{
                    c.getCodigo(),
                    c.getDataEntrada(),
                    c.getDataSaida(),
                    c.getNome(),
                    c.getEndereco(),
                    c.getNumero(),
                    c.getComplemento(),
                    c.getBairro(),
                    c.getCidade(),
                    c.getEstado(),
                    c.getPai(),
                    c.getMae(),
                    c.getDataNasc(),
                    c.getRg(),
                    c.getCpf(),
                    c.getGrauEscolar(),
                    c.getTelefone(),
                    c.getCelular(),
                    c.getEstCivil(),
                    c.getTiposDrogas(),
                    c.getTentParar(),
                    c.getDetParar(),
                    c.getEstPreso(),
                    c.getMotPreso(),
                    c.getDataCriacao()
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logger.getLogger(AplicaCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }




        jtCadInterno.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(14).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(15).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(16).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(17).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(18).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(19).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(20).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(21).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(22).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(23).setPreferredWidth(500);
        jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(24).setPreferredWidth(500);

        jtCadInterno.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jtCadInterno = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jtCadInterno.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "Data Entrada", "Data Saida", "Nome", "Endereço", "Número", "Complemento", "Bairro", "Cidade", "Estado", "Nome Pai", "Nome Mãe", "Nascido em", "RG", "CPF", "Grau Escolar", "Telefone", "Celular", "Estado Civil", "Drogas Usadas", "Tentou Parar?", "Detalhe de Como Tentou Parar", "Esteve Preso?", "Motivo Pelo Qual Foi Preso", "Cadastrado em"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jtCadInterno.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1272, 503));
        jtCadInterno.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1272, 503));
        jtCadInterno.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1272, 503));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jtCadInterno);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1270, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(89, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 531, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFAltExc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new JFAltExc().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jtCadInterno;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Se vocês observarem, eu defini um tamanho de 500 para cada campo, com a intenção de testar, fazendo com que todos campos fiquem bem grande e abra espaço para rolagem horizontal, permitindo visualizar o conteúdo de todos os campos, porém como ele NÃO ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO e o tamanho não altera, ele divide em um tamanho menor mas igualando o tamanho de todos os campos.

Qualquer coisa posso postar mais detalhes.

Comment: Tente isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165066/como-eu-defino-tamanho-de-colunas

Comment: Tentei, porém os campos que não couberam na tela simplesmente desapareceram, mas os que ficaram , foi exibido no tamanho correto.

Comment: Lucas, esse codigo não é testavel. Tem como você editar com uma tabela contendo algumas linhas com dados de exemplo?

Comment: Desculpa, mas não entendi o que vc precisa que eu faça, poderia explicar por favor. Obrigado :)

Comment: Há dependencias no seu código. Precisa de conexao com seu banco, o que é inviavel. Remova as dependencias do entitymanager e do seu banco, e adicione umas 2 ou 3 linhas manualmente para servir de exemplo.

Comment: @diegofm Engraçado, conforme solicitado, fui criar uma versão para teste, sem comunicação com o Banco de Dados, porém funcionou corretamente. Será que tem a ver com o processo de chamar os dados para a tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Você colocou o jtCadInterno.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 2x no código, bem apague o primeiro e mude o de baixo para "AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS"

Você também pode fazer assim:

.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100); //Tamanho convencional da coluna
.getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(500);       //Tamanho máximo que ela pode chegar

Comment: Mas isso só vai reduzir o tamanho de todas as colunas de modo que todas apareçam sem scroll. É com esse tanto de coluna, não vai exibir o conteúdo. Logo essa solução não vai resolver o problema pro completo.

Comment: Isso mesmo, não resolveu, porque o código juntou tudo para caber em uma tela, mas obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @LucasH.Rosa você olhou a resposta da pergunta que deixei o link? Tenho quase certeza de que ela atende a este problema.

Comment: @diegofm olhei, porém os campos que não couberam na tela simplesmente desapareceram, mas os que ficaram , foi exibido no tamanho correto.

Comment: @OKOL, tentei dessa segunda forma que vc passou, mas os campos que não couberam na tela simplesmente desapareceram, mas os que ficaram , foram exibidos corretamente.

Comment: @diegofm Testei aqui, com o AUTO_RESIZE_OFF fica da forma que você quer, mas terá que arrumar cada coluna com o PreferredWidth, pra ficar bonito né, testa ai.

Comment: Das 24 colunas? Aí a solução deixa de ser prática.

Comment: Rapaz faça um: `for(int i=0;i<25;i++){jtCadInterno.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(100);
                   }` Desculpem as várias edições, comecei hoje no fórum kkk

Comment: Ainda sim isso soa meio que gambiarra, forçar a definir o tamanho manualmente, e se as colunas tiverem dados que precisa de tamanho diferentes? Acho que esse caso é preciso analisar o conteudo da linha para definir o tamanho da coluna, e não chutar um valor, pois pode não ser o valor que a coluna precisa.

Comment: Vou montar o FOR e pegar o tamanho da maior linha de dados para definir no parâmetro, porém antes queria arrumar fazer funcionar para depois implementar esses detalhes.

Comment: @OKOL no meu não funcionou, estou trabalhando com as ferramentas do Java JFrame pegando o componente TABELA do "Controles Swing"

Comment: Mas é claro, você esta totalmente correto, dessa forma cada coluna será definida com o mesmo tamanho, porém você pode clicar nela e aumentar o tamanho, ela vai empurra as outras aumentando/diminuindo o tamanho do scroll. Para perfeição você criar uma classe que conte qual linha tem a maior quantidade de caracteres e baseado nisso você define o tamanho das colunas, mais isso já será outra duvida. Basta explorar as possibilidades da classe JTable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: @LucasH.Rosa pra tabela se adequar ao conteudo, nada disso funcionará, você precisa fazer o código calcular o tamanho necessário para a celula. Mas sem um [mcve] que te pedi, fica dificil sugerir algo.

Comment: @OKOL `O meu problema é que são 24 colunas para serem exibidos nessa tabela, sendo assim não consigo visualizar todos os dados conforme o necessário.`  - a dúvida é justamente essa, conforme essa frase do autor da pergunta, é adequar o conteudo das colunas.

Comment: @OKOL Consegui fazer aqui, obrigado pela ajuda. Abs.

Comment: @diegofm Consegui fazer aqui, obrigado pela ajuda. Abs.

Comment: Vou postar como ficou o código funcional na pergunta.